# get ReadStream object in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-drive-api, fs

I want to upload a file in vue js using the google drive api.

the example from the site uses fs.createReadStream() in order to read a file and pass it to the api like this:

```
let media = {
      mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
      body: fs.createReadStream('path of the image')
    };

let objInfo = {
 ...
      media: media,
 ...   
}

drive.files.create(objInfo,...)
```

This code doesn't work in the browser because i cannot use the fs library.

Is there an alternative to createReadStream() function for the browser?

I have tried with fetch() but it returns a ReadbleStream but i need a ReadStream

Comment: For example, as a workaround, can you use ``fs.readFile()``?

Comment: i cannot use fs in browser context

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I apologize my comment was not useful for your situation.

Comment: don't worry! Thanks ;)